# Can enabling Windows Features be blocked for local admins?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I am working on an installer of a windows application. Due to its dependencies, to make it work, multiple applications need to be installed and also some changes to the [windows features](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=windows+features+on%2foff&view=detail&mid=AC15E55C8ABBD0888592AC15E55C8ABBD0888592&FORM=VIRE) (turning on some windows features) are required.

My installer is supposed to be used by companies. In companies, it can be the case that someone has the rights to install software (in program files folder) but is still restricted (for example updates are regulated by the IT department). A typical explanation for this is that someone is a local admin but not necessarily a global admin.

Can it be the case that someone is allowed to install software in the program files folder but restricted in enabling windows features? I need to know this because this would simply mean that my installer should not automatically/automated enable such windows features. It may work on my VM, but it can fail on the customer employee desktop which would cause the installation to fail due to missing rights for one specific action: enabling some windows features.

Can enabling Windows Features be blocked for local admins?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/36a1aa80-9108-425c-ae86-bb82043c403f/turn-windows-features-on-or-off-using-group-policy?forum=win10itprosetup) there's no group policies to control Windows features. Therefore we could assume that you're safe for now.